# c# Creating User plans

Tags: c#

i want to create a plans system for my program 
for example

```
basic plan => 1 month
```

in the register method , when the user pick that plan in the `subscription Table` it adds for him `30 Days + the started date`

here is the table

```
Table [Subscribes]
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NULL,
    [Pack] [int] NULL,
    [Subscription] [int] NULL,
    [InstallDate] [date] NULL
```

so when the user login into his account i need to check for the plan so i made it as simple as i can **(for learning purpose)**

```
    public DataTable Check()
    {
        DataTable Table = new DataTable();
        Acces _Acces = new Network___Acces.Acces();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[0].Value = User_info.UserID;
        Table = _Acces._SelectData("CheckSubscription", param);
        return Table;
    }
```

this method return all the plan info for that user

and my checkmethod :

```
    public void Subscription()
    {
        DateTime From = (DateTime)Check().Rows[0][4];
        int Days = (int)Check().Rows[0][3];
        if (From.AddDays((double)Days) >= DateTime.Now)
        {
                //time ended !
        }
        else
        {
                // still in the plan
        }
    }
```

is there is any other **SIMPLE** way to do , i don't need any advanced project about plans yet.

**Edit :** its a payment Plans system

because on MSDN [DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx)

it takes the Actual Date of the local computer wich means we can add days whenever the plan ended

Comment: I take you are talking about payment plan, not plan of action or flat-plan? Anyway, what is not simple about your solution?

Comment: yes  payment plan , i m asking if there is any other simple ways

Comment: Probably there  are other ways. You have not told us why your way is not good enough and why you are looking for another solution - this will help people to direct you.

Comment: You can use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server to create tables in the database and you can manually add rows to table if you don't want to write code in c# to create the table data.

Comment: @trailmax on the MSDN [DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx) says that the DateTime.now takes the actual date of the local computer wich means we can add days to the computer whenever the plan ended

Comment: Yes, that's possible. That should be part of the question/concern. Please edit the question to add this concern. I'm afraid your question in the current form can not be answered properly.

Comment: @trailmax Edited ! thanks sir

Comment: Wait so are you worried about the user tampering with the computer's date time value allowing him/her to have an active subscription all the time?

Comment: @Searching yes sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general time stamps  are done with the system/computer value, like SQL GETDATE(), DateTime.Now..  and so on.
Given that connecting to internet is NOT an option, validating the authenticity of datetime is probably hard.

These are only plausible ways that you can use to find out if user has tampered with system clock and do your checking..

- Save user last login to a table

  - on 31st day if they reset their computer clock, your table will still have a record stating that it already exists or is invalid
- When account is created, save datetime to a file which is stored in system dir

  - You may encrypt the details
  - The program will need to check the file in the beginning, if they delete it just disable their account

The user can always find a work around if they spend time. These are only tips, given time is an object to always consider.

If connecting to internet is an option available, just query the time from a remote source and compare with it instead of the local computer.